# How to label images once importing them in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a set of pictures, which are labelled dog, cat, truck, airplane and car in a folder. Once I import them in to python I want to assign them binary labels. The following code shows how I can extract pictures from the folder and do it for 1 class but how can I do it for multiple classes? For example 1 for 'dog', 2 for 'cat', 3 for 'truck', 4 for 'airplane' and 5 for 'car'.

```
Test_dir = "C:/Users/Instructor/Dropbox/Data Science/2.Temp_WORDFILES/test"
image_width = 32
image_height = 32

def read_images(directory, resize_to=(128, 128)):

"""This function extracts images from given
directory"""

    files = glob.glob(directory + "/*.jpg")
    images = []
    labels = []
    for f in tqdm.tqdm_notebook(files):
        im = Image.open(f)
        im = im.resize(resize_to)
        im = np.array(im) / 255.0
        im = im.astype("float32")
        images.append(im)

        label = 1 if "dog" in f.lower() else 0
        labels.append(label)

    return np.array(images), np.array(labels)

 X, y = read_images(directory=Test_dir, resize_to=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Test_dir = "C:/Users/Instructor/Dropbox/Data Science/2.Temp_WORD     FILES/test"
image_width = 32
image_height = 32

def read_images(directory, resize_to=(128, 128)):

    """This function extracts images from given
    directory"""

    files = glob.glob(directory + "/*.jpg")
    images = []
    labels = []
    switch_values = {'dog':1,'cat':2, 'truck':3, 'airplane':4 ,'car':5}
    for f in tqdm.tqdm_notebook(files):
        im = Image.open(f)
        im = im.resize(resize_to)
        im = np.array(im) / 255.0
        im = im.astype("float32")
        images.append(im)

        label = switch_values.get(f.lower())
        labels.append(label)

    return np.array(images), np.array(labels)

 X, y = read_images(directory=Test_dir, resize_to=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT))
```

Comment: returns y as array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) and not the classes

Answer (score 0):

Define a dictionary to map the animal name to label

```
animal_to_label = {'dog': 1,'cat': 2,'truck': 3,'airplane': 4,'car': 5 }

Test_dir = "C:/Users/Instructor/Dropbox/Data Science/2.Temp_WORDFILES/test"
image_width = 32
image_height = 32

def read_images(directory, resize_to=(128, 128)):

"""This function extracts images from given
directory"""

    files = glob.glob(directory + "/*.jpg")
    images = []
    labels = []
    switch_values = {'dog':1,'cat':2, 'truck':3, 'airplane':4 ,'car':5}
    for f in tqdm.tqdm_notebook(files):
        im = Image.open(f)
        im = im.resize(resize_to)
        im = np.array(im) / 255.0
        im = im.astype("float32")
        images.append(im)
        name = f.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
        label = animal_to_label[name.lower()]
        labels.append(label)

    return np.array(images), np.array(labels)

 X, y = read_images(directory=Test_dir, resize_to=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT))
```

Comment: returns y as array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) and not the classes

Comment: The files are simply named dog, cat, truck, airplane and car